# Fill ArrayList on new Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

When I start my App first the `main Activity` gets called. I have an `ArrayList` in this Activity which gets populated via an `Intent`. the problem is that my App crashes if I want to start it (I get a `null pointer exception` I guess because there is no `Intent` at this point of the procedure). However, from this Activity you can call another Activity where you are able to enter some data and this data gets sent via the mentioned `Intent` to the `main Activity` to populate the `ArrayList`. I've tried to populate it inside a `on new Intent` method (and this way it did not crash) but nothing happened to my `ArrayList`.

Does someone know how I can fix this? Thank you.

Here's my method:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent depositIntent) {
    super.onNewIntent(depositIntent);
    if(depositIntent.getStringExtra("CHECK").equals("yes")){

        DepositInputValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTVALUE");
        DepositInputDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTDATE");
        DepositInputNote = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTNOTE");

        float newValue = Float.parseFloat(DepositInputValue);
        int newDate = Integer.parseInt(DepositInputDate);

        myTransactions.add(new Transaction(newValue, newDate, DepositInputNote));
    }
}
```

And this is my onCreate Method: (note: I do not try to get the Intent twice in this class (on new Intent method and this one). I always comment one of those out)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assets_overview);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fabplus = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
    fabplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AssetsOverview.this, AddMoneyTransaction.class));
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fabminus = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabRemove);
    fabminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AssetsOverview.this, RemoveMoneyTransaction.class));
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fabhint = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabHint);
    fabhint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AssetsOverview.this, HintMoneyTransaction.class));
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //transaction list

    //populateTransactionList();
    populateListView();


    DepositInputValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTVALUE");
    DepositInputDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTDATE");
    DepositInputNote = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTNOTE");

    float newValue = Float.parseFloat(DepositInputValue);
    int newDate = Integer.parseInt(DepositInputDate);

    myTransactions.add(new Transaction(newValue, newDate, DepositInputNote));

    //calculate and set current (actual) balance

    TextView balance_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance_view);
    balance_view.setText(newValue + newDate + DepositInputNote + " $");

}
```

Comment: can you share what log cat say?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: As an aside, if you make `Transaction` Parcelable or Serializeable you can add these objects directly to an intent rather than their contents.

Comment: Also, use the Intent parameter instead of calling getIntent()

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if I do it like shown in my examplethere is no error, it simply does not add an item to my ArrayList and how do you mean I should use the Intent parameter?

Comment: @LukasSchröder Use the Intent parameter like you already do in the if condition. Note that you can also put a float directly in an intent without parsing it as a string. Where in your onNewIntent() method do you add elements to the ArrayList. Remember that a computer does exactly as you tell it. No more. No less. You must explicitly do something with the list in order for it to contain data. You should also show the code which caused the NullPointerException so we can help there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice myTransactions is my ArrayList so in the line myTransactions.add(new Transaction(newValue, newDate, DepositInputNote)); I want to add it to the array list. The NULL pointer exception appears if I move the getIntent() to my oncreate method.

Comment: @LukasSchröder please show the exact code which caused the NPE. Explaining code in words just wastes your time.

Comment: Also be sure to show all relevant declarations to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice okay I added the onCreate method above

Comment: Which line in onCreate() causes the NPE?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the getIntent lines as there is no Intent when I start the App for the first time

Comment: @LukasSchröder Only one specific line will throw an exception. Which one is it?

Comment: Every activity is always started with an intent.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are creating an accounting app. You  should use a database to store data permanently. Each activity can read directly from the database and you do not need to bother with using an Intent to send lists of data between activities.

In the version that uses onCreate(), most likely the cause of the NPE is that getExtras() returns null because there is no "extras" bundle in the intent. Note that you already have this Bundle as a parameter, so there is no need to call `getIntent().getExtras()`. Instead use `savedInstanceState`. You must also check that it is not null before using it:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    DepositInputValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTVALUE");
    DepositInputDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTDATE");
    DepositInputNote = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEPOSITINPUTNOTE");
    float newValue = Float.parseFloat(DepositInputValue);
    int newDate = Integer.parseInt(DepositInputDate); myTransactions.add(new Transaction(newValue, newDate, DepositInputNote));

    //calculate and set current (actual) balance TextView
    balance_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance_view);
    balance_view.setText(newValue + newDate + DepositInputNote + " $"); 
}
```

Note that you can simplify this coffee by putting the float directly in the Intents extras instead of putting it as a String. Then you can get the float directly rather than parsing it from a string. Also, you can make Transaction implement Parcelable.

Comment: Thank you I did not think of that. I will try this later on